# Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /app1/backend

COPY ./target/app1-backend.jar app1-backend.jar

ADD cloudfront_private_key.pem /host_files/

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-cp", "app1-backend.jar", "hsnbe.app1"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app1:
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
    image: app1-server:development
    container_name: health_backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/DockerfileHS.dev
      target: app1
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh/health_backend_dev_cloudfront_private_key.pem:${HAPP_AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_FILE_PATH:-/host_files/health_backend_dev_cloudfront_private_key.pem}
    ports:
      - ${APP1_PORT:-9000}:9000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
```

Error:

```
Reason CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/app1/backend, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

What I've tried already:

1. Docker Login Succeeded, but if I try to docker pull from registry returns:
   Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/app1/backend/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden

Comment: I don't see anything in the compose file or Dockerfile that points to Gitlab. Where does that reference come from? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR:

Check:

1. Are you [logged in](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/authenticate_with_container_registry.html)? Look in `~/.docker/config.json` for `auths` section
2. The Auth token needs `read_repository` *and* `write_repository` scopes
3. Check the [container registry visibility](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#change-visibility-of-the-container-registry). If the container is only visible to *Reporter* or higher, then the user which made the token needs to have that [role](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html)
4. Does the project already exist on GitLab? You can't push to arbitrary or new namespace
5. Did you build / tag with the same name?

---

### Access Denied for GitLab Container Registry

The `access denied` can be because the [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) (PAT) which you are using does not have [access to the project for this container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#authenticate-with-the-container-registry).

- The PAT must have `read_registry` [scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#personal-access-token-scopes) to be able to pull, and *also* `write_registry` scope, if you want to push to the container registry
- The GitLab User who owns the PAT must have [permission](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#project-members-permissions) to access the GitLab Project which owns this container registry:

  - For a `docker push` to a Private project, you need at least *Developer* access to that project
  - For `docker pull`, it is enough to be a *Guest*
  - If the container's visibility is **Only Project Members**, you need at least *Reporter* access

You cannot use [deploy tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/index.html) with the public API. They are only useful for CI/CD jobs.

### Invalid tag name

Another reason for `access denied` can be if the project does not actually exist. You can't push to arbitrary namespaces in GitLab. In your example, the error says:

```
access denied for registry.gitlab.com/app1/backend
```

There is no "`backend`" project in `@app1`'s namespace. This may not even be your namespace: http://gitlab.com/app1

There's not quite enough detail in the question, but as a guess, you should probably be doing this, substituting your username or group name for `$GITLAB_USERNAME`, and the project's namespace for `$GITLAB_PROJECT_NAMESPACE`:

```
docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/$GITLAB_USERNAME/$GITLAB_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/app1/backend:1.0

docker push registry.gitlab.com/$GITLAB_USERNAME/$GITLAB_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/app1/backend:1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was helpful. For pull access, rules have changed now it seems: "The ability to view the Container Registry and pull images is controlled by the Container Registry’s visibility permissions". For our set up, where project members were allowed access to container registry, I had to change the role to `Reporter`.

Comment: That's helpful information to add, I updated it in the checklist (step 3)

Comment: About to check the answer but just out of curiosity why is `write_api`  required for a PULL (a read request) from registry? I am getting the error with Kaniko.

Comment: @rbaleksandarr, you've made me spot an error in my answer and I'll update: it requires `read_repository` (not `read_registry` as I wrote in 2022) to do a `git pull`, and `write_repository` to `git push` to the repository. You don't need `write_` to PULL... The `_registry` scopes are for the container registry, by bad. There is no `write_api`, but the `api` scope allows REST Create, Update, and Delete operations (`POST`,`PUT`,`PATCH` and `DELETE`), whereas `read_api` only allows Reads (`GET`) through the API. Permissions also still count.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed `gitlab-runner` locally via `apt-get` and had the same issue.

I was able to fix the issue only I removed the installed `gitlab-runner` and reinstall it via `curl`

```bash
curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash

sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner
```